# icCube - ETL - how to execute a file dump

Tags: etl, iccube

In the icCube ETL, there is a data manipulation (data view) called "File dump". I have set-up a couple of them in the ETL process, but none are executed when the data is loaded into icCube.

This is a simple version of what I do:

```
data source 1 > data view: a > used in FACTS
data source 1 > data view: a > data view: file dump
```

The file dump is not executed, as I do not see a file on the server.

How to achieve that during load, there is alway a file dump available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure the view is actually used in either building the dimensions or the facts. This is a pass through view so it can be used like the underlying the table with no problem.

So in your example "data view: file dump" should be the 'table' feeding the facts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I followed your approach and did: a > file dump > used in FACTS. But now the FACTS are empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: More likely you are not checking the file at the right place: double check your view definition.