# icCube - ETL - Creating a File dump and then use it as data source

Tags: etl, iccube

Following [the question on how to execute a file dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638482/iccube-etl-how-to-execute-a-file-dump) in icCube, I would like to know it it is possible to:

1. create a file dump
2. then use it as a data source

I tried to build a sequence of data views, but I can not get it to work, and I wonder if it is even possible at al?

(The reason I would like to do it is that my main data source is an odata feed and I need a lot of data manipulation before I can load it. I anticipate that it will be much easier to do these on CSV files.)

Comment: Looks like no. But do not understand the rationale of having a file dump. You can transform the result of the ODATA feed directly. Why having an intermediate file?

Comment: With the odata feed I continuously run into a cycle error. To avoid it I have to consult three times the same odata source.  I hope to avoid that with one download to CSV file format and then process the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as the rationale behind the ETL support is to transform data-tables as returned by the data-sources.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. I hoped that once this was possible, it would be a tiny leap to dump the contents in a SQL table and have (1) SQL manipulations available, with which I am really familiar and (2) have a drill through available (which is only available for a relational data source)